# Group by based on an if statement

Tags: pandas, if-statement, pandas-groupby

I have a df that contains ids and timestamps.

I was looking to **group by** the id and then a condition on the timestamp in the two rows.
Something like **if timestamp_col1 > timestamp_col1 for the second row then 1 else 2**

Basically grouping the ids and an if statement to give a value of 1 if the first row timestamp is < than the second and 2 if the second row timestamp is < then the first

[image: df sample below]

Updated output below where last two values should be 2
[image: Updated Output]

Comment: why don't you provide a sample input dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) for converting `time`s, then aggregate difference between first and last value and compare by [`gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.gt.html) (`>`), last [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for assign new column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID Code': ['a','a','b','b'],
    'Time Created': ['21:25:27','21:12:09','21:12:00','21:12:40']
})

df['Time Created'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time Created'])

mask = df.groupby('ID Code')['Time Created'].agg(lambda x: x.iat[0] < x.iat[-1])
print (mask)
ID Code
a     True
b    False
Name: Time Created, dtype: bool

df['new'] = np.where(df['ID Code'].map(mask), 1, 2)
print (df)
  ID Code Time Created  new
0       a     21:25:27    2
1       a     21:12:09    2
2       b     21:12:00    1
3       b     21:12:40    1
```

Another solution with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for return aggregate value to new column, here boolean mask:

```
df['Time Created'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time Created'])

mask = (df.groupby('ID Code')['Time Created'].transform(lambda x: x.iat[0] > x.iat[-1]))
print (mask)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: Time Created, dtype: bool

df['new'] = np.where(mask, 2, 1)
print (df)
  ID Code Time Created  new
0       a     21:25:27    2
1       a     21:12:09    2
2       b     21:12:00    1
3       b     21:12:40    1
```

Comment: I am sorry I explained wrong, I am trying to do a conditional if off of the same col bu in two different rows.

Comment: @Chris90 - Can you add [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: @Chris90 - there are always 2 values in each group ?

Comment: yeah for this df there are only 2 rows per ID

Comment: Thanks. question where you have total seconds why do you have seconds over minutes?

Comment: @Chris90 - not necessary, is possible compare with `0 Timedelta`, edited answer.

Comment: Thanks so the result above gives me the same df back with a new column with the value of 1 or 2 depending on if the timestamp is > or < in the first or second grouped by row vs. a grouped by df result that just has the 1 or 2 valued for the aggregated or grouped by rows correct?

Comment: @Chris90 - good commentm just realised I overcomplicated solution, simplier is compare per groups. It compare first and last value per groups, because only 2 rows per groups.

Comment: I get this error when trying both methods:
ValueError: only leading negative signs are allowed

Comment: I think its because my dates include days?  @jezrael

2018-12-13 20:12:41.750

Comment: @Chris90 I think yes, need change `to_timedelta` to `to_datetime`

Comment: Thanks - This works in terms of executing, but it the end result it gives me all 1s in the new column even when it should be false or 2 why is that? @jezrael

Comment: I added the output above where it is only outputting the value 1

using youre first method @jezrael

Comment: @Chris90 Is necessary specify format of datetime, use `df['Time Created'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time Created'], format='%m/%d/%y %h:%m')`

Comment: I still get the same 1 value for all rows, when when I add 

`df_nonroute['dropoff_complete_time_utc'] = pd.to_datetime(df_nonroute['dropoff_complete_time_utc'],format='%m/%d/%y %h:%m:%s')`

the timestamp looks like this
`2018-12-25 22:24:04.764`

@jezrael

Comment: @Chris90 What about `s = df['id'].value_counts()` and `print (s[s!=2])`? Because it seems there is multiple values per groups. If still problem, is possible sent me your real data to my email and I can check it. Becauae it seems data related problem.

Comment: it seems to work for the first method but not the transform method as in the transform method it only populates all rows with 1 @jezrael